# Unable to start app with SplashScreen and WebView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

I'm **unable to run my Android app**: https://github.com/iSCApps/isc.apps.android.videofy.

> I created **Splash.java** and **MainActivity.java**.

*Splash.java:*

```
package isc.apps.android.videofy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        final Handler handel = new Handler();
        handel.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent loadSplash = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(loadSplash);

                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java:*

```
package isc.apps.android.videofy;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
private static final String TAG = "Main";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.trnity);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressBar.setMessage("Trinity tuts loading...");
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressBar.show();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Loading");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Done loading " + url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("https://isc-host.github.io/videos.isc");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

> The app keeps crashing on my Android 4.0.3.

I also run `adb logcat` on a Nexus S emulator on Android Studio:

```
- waiting for device -
error: protocol fault (status read)
```

> Do you know where the code error is?

Comment: Splash screen is not recommended. You can look at the stack trace for exceptions and fix the crash

Comment: The code error is in the `logcat`: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be with this line:

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.trnity);
```

In activity_main the id of webView is videofy and in the code its trnity.